# MongoDB C# Mono

Tags: c#, mongodb, mono

I'm having problems checking that the mongodb is alive when connecting from c#. The code below shows what I'm trying to do. I'm expecting an exception if mongodb is not available. However, the code runs without exception even if mongodb is not on. Later on the code will then timeout with task exception when trying to query the db.

My platform is OS X, Mono 4.0.3, Xamarin, MongoDB driver 2.0.1.

Does other platforms such as Windows throw the exception.

Or is there another way to verify that the DB is live?

Best, Hu

```cs
MongoClient client = new MongoClient( "mongodb://localhost:27017" );
try
{
    IMongoDatabase db = client.GetDatabase( "clientservertest" ); 
    // Should throw exception if not connected
    m_collection = db.GetCollection<T>( collection );
    m_connected = true;
}
catch( Exception )
{
    m_connected = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The "monogodb//" style URI have been an issue in throwing exceptions, try grabbing the databases Stats in a try/catch:

```
MongoClient client = new MongoClient( "mongodb://localhost:27017" );
try
{
    IMongoDatabase db = client.GetDatabase( "clientservertest" );
    try (
       db.GetStats();
       m_connected = true;
    catch (MongoConnectionException) {
       m_connected = false;
    }   
}
catch( Exception ) // Generic exception
{
    m_connected = false;
}
```

And depending upon the version that you are using, there is a Server Ping() method that you can use. Get the server object from your client ( var server = client.GetServer() ) and ping it ( server.Ping() ).

Answer (score 0):

That seems to be the old API. I'm currently on 2.0. Anyway, I eventually did a ping to the db. In my case the mongodb is running on the same box so I'm not waiting for more than 1 second for an answer.

```
/// <summary>
/// Ping the specified db.
/// </summary>
private bool Ping( IMongoDatabase db )
{
    Console.WriteLine( "Checking mongodb connection..." );
    Task<BsonDocument> pingTask = db.RunCommandAsync<BsonDocument>( new BsonDocument( "ping", 1 ) );
    pingTask.Wait( 1000 ); // more than one second is way too much - db should be on same computer
    if( pingTask.IsCompleted )
    {
        Console.WriteLine( "...connection ok." );
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine( "...connection FAILED." );
        return false;
    }
}
```